# Can't locate Understand/license.pm in @INC Error

Tags: perl, metrics

I want to run my perl script which suppose to use the "Understand Scitool Perl API". I have included the statement "use Understand;" in the script have  but when I tun the it on the terminal, it keeps showing me this error:
"Can't locate Understand/license.pm in @INC". 
Does anyone know how can I install "Understand" module in order to be able to use its library knowing that I have already installed "Understand" tool.

*Note: Im working on Mac operating system.*

Comment: *"Mac operating system"* could be one of very many different systems that Apple have produced. You need to be much more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The SciTools `Understand` module requires a licence in the form of a `license.pm` file

If you're doing this at work then you should speak to your system administrator or manager to get hold of one. If you're working on your own then you need to talk to SciTools

Where did you get the main `Understand` module from?

Comment: Im working on my own, I got my license from my college.

Comment: @user2061337: So you have a `license.pm` file? What have you done with it?

Comment: where am I supposed to find it? :/

Comment: I don't know! You said you got it from your college. Where did you put it?

Comment: I have no files in my device related to Understand except for the app it self. Maybe the best thing is to contact my supervisor about the module, thanks

Comment: @user2061337: You say *"I got my license from my college"* so what did you get?

Comment: I got the Understand tool

Comment: @user2061337: So did you get a licence?

Comment: @user2061337: *`Understand::license(name)`*

*Specify a regcode string, or a specific path to an Understand license.*

Comment: Can you tell me the exact syntax that I should put? lets assume that my license code is abc123. shall I type:  Understand::license(abc123); or with cotaions or how? because I have tried both cases but still not working :(